# How get Tensorflow shape

Tags: tensorflow, shapes

I have the following constant in TensorFlow:

```
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]], [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]]])
```

Now I want to know its shape. I have tried to run:

```
tf.shape(t)
```

I get:
    `<tf.Tensor 'Shape:0' shape=(3,) dtype=int32>`

I thought i should see something like [2,2,3]. How can I read the expected shape value?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `tf.get_shape()`, which returns the TensorShape.